# Extractung features from CNN (Xception model), I got IsADirectoryError?

Tags: python, image, google-colaboratory, feature-extraction

**to extract features from xcption model**
I'm working on Image caption generator using cnn and lstm and i shared the code i got from a site.  I tried to solve it but when i do changes in code I'm getting error on some other part so can anyone plaese tell me how to solve this

```
def extract_features(directory):
        model = Xception( include_top=False, pooling='avg' )
        features = {}
        for img in tqdm(os.walk(directory)):
            filename = directory + "/" + img
            image = Image.open(filename)
            image = image.resize((299,299))
            image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
            #image = preprocess_input(image)
            image = image/127.5
            image = image - 1.0

            feature = model.predict(image)
            features[img] = feature
        return features

#2048 feature vector
features = extract_features(dataset_images)
dump(features, open("features.p","wb"))
```

**error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5f1d4e4e3211> in <module>()
     16 
     17 #2048 feature vector
---> 18 features = extract_features(dataset_images)
     19 dump(features, open("features.p","wb"))

<ipython-input-8-5f1d4e4e3211> in extract_features(directory)
      3         features = {}
      4         for img in tqdm(os.walk(directory)):
----> 5             filename = directory + "/" + img
      6             image = Image.open(filename)
      7             image = image.resize((299,299))

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns both files and directories. So you are trying to open a directory using `Image.open`

Comment: yes , I want to open a image dataset . Do I need to use some other code to open a directory ?  Actually I changed  'os.listdir()' to 'os.walk'  and the ' IsADirectory ' error  is solved but i got some other error .

Comment: btw what is your new error?

Comment: I have updated the new error i got after the changes i made  . can you please look into it , I'm stuck there

Answer (score 0):

- In your case `img` in `filename = directory + "/" + img` is a tuple and `directory` is a string, so they cannot be concatenated.
- So you have loop through `img`. In that case you might get another error because `img` includes root directory and sub directories.

  ```
  def extract_features(directory):
              model = Xception( include_top=False, pooling='avg' )
              features = {}
              for (root,dirs,files) in tqdm(os.walk(directory)):
                  for img in files:
                      filename = directory + "/" + img
                      image = Image.open(filename)
                      image = image.resize((299,299))
                      image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
                      #image = preprocess_input(image)
                      image = image/127.5
                      image = image - 1.0
                      feature = model.predict(image)
                      features[img] = feature
              return features
  ```

Comment: I tried using the the code you've given but i got this error       ...... 


 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Project/Flickr8k_Dataset (1).zip (Unzipped Files)/446291803_2fd4641b99.jpg'

Comment: you might have to unzip the file at the same location and delete zipped file if the images are inside a zipped folder. can add a screenshot of file structure?

Comment: Actually the error has been solved now, It was my mistake coz the path i  given was wrong, now evertying is good. You are the one who has been helping me through out  and thank you so much for ur help and effort. Again thanks a lot......